# How can I convert text to speech (mp3 file) in python?

Tags: python, audio, mp3, text-to-speech

I can convert text to speech in python using puttsx. and I can do record audio using microphone(headphone) to mp3 file.

What I want to do is to convert text to mp3 file.
Is there a way to store audio playing using pyttsx to memory or unicode string.

Can anyone help me storing audio to memory, or how I can convert that string to mp3 file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not know about pyttsx, but a while ago I used the Google TTS API to generate MP3s from text.

You can get an idea of how it works from [this code snippet](http://pastebin.com/VcSSzTHu). The free version of Google TTS is limited to a certain number of letters for each request, So I'd recommend splitting the text into sentences and creating a file for each sentence.

If you need help with that, please tell me.

Comment: I will try this technique at my end first. If i got any problem will ask you for help.

Comment: Note that Google Translate only accepts up to 100 characters via this method.

Comment: Yes. As I was not sure if this limit would evolve over time I did not mention precise numbers.

Comment: It returns: urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 503: Service Unavailable

Answer (score 5):

To generate the Audio file from the text file, i am using this code i hope it can help you

```
from comtypes.client import CreateObject    
engine = CreateObject("SAPI.SpVoice")
stream = CreateObject("SAPI.SpFileStream")
from comtypes.gen import SpeechLib
infile = "SHIVA.txt"
outfile = "SHIVA-audio.wav"
stream.Open(outfile, SpeechLib.SSFMCreateForWrite)
engine.AudioOutputStream = stream
f = open(infile, 'r')
theText = f.read()
f.close()
engine.speak(theText)
stream.Close()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can bypass the 100 character rule by splitting the 'theText' string into an array: `theText = f.read().split("<null>")` (i used "<null>" as the delimiter) put the delimiter in the text every sentence or space before 100 characters.
Create a for-loop: `for section in theText:` and every section run `engine.Speak(section)`

I hope this helps with 100 character limits!